# javascript checking input value with dynamic table row value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

First of all, English is not my native language, so I am not really able to search for the starting point or clues. Secondly, what I am trying to achieve is javascript that will check whether the input by the user is equal to the value in a table that is provided by the system. If the value is not equal, then the user is required to add a note. Without further ado, here is my script:

```
<tbody>
  <?php
  foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='value1'>".$value[1]."</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='number' class='inputuser' required value=''> ".$value[2]."</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='text' class='note'></tr>";}
?>
  </tbody></table>
    <button type="submit" id="approve" >approve</button>
</div></form>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    let input = document.getElementByClass("inputuser"); 
    let note = document.getElementByCLass("note");
    input.addEventListener("input", validate);    

    function validate(){
      if(input.value === "supposedly value of td with class value1"){
        note.setAttribute("required","required");
      } else {
        note.removeAttribute("required");  
      }
    }    });
  </script>
```

I am lost as to how to get the value of "td" in the table with class `value1`, and I used a `foreach` loop because the table has more than 1 row. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to this by adding a data-attribute into the HTML that is produced by the PHP - for example, on the `input.inputuser` element. I think this is easier than trying to have PHP produce a JavaScript data structure in which all of the values can be looked-up.

I do not know PHP, but looking at the code you have provided, I would guess that the syntax would be:

```
<input type='number' class='inputuser' data-expected='" . $value[1] . "' required value=''>
```

When the `input.inputuser` elements "know" their expected values, we can easily attach a listener that will compare the actual value of the input with what is defined as expected in the attribute.

We can use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach our listener at the `<tr>` level, so as to easily get the row of the changed `input.inputuser` and, so, easily get the corresponding `input.note`.

Note: In my example code I am using [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) to generate the HTML - this is serving the role that the PHP is in your example.

```js
const rowTemplate = Handlebars.compile(`
  {{#each values as |value|}}
    <tr>
      <td class="value1">{{value}}</td>
      <td>
        <input class="inputuser" data-expected="{{value}}" required type="number">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="note" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
`);

const values = [2, 7, 5, 3];
$('tbody').append(rowTemplate({ values }));

$(function() {
  $('tr').on('input', 'input.inputuser', function (event) {
    const $this = $(this);
    const actualValue = Number($this.val()) || 0;
    const expectedValue = $this.data('expected');
    
    $(event.delegateTarget).find('input.note').prop('required', actualValue === expectedValue);
  });
});
```

```css
input.note[required] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="approve">approve</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: whoa, thank you, i dont aware there is such 'data-expected', this work like a charm, thanks

Comment: @cadmad You are welcome. To be clear, `data-expected` is a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). data-attributes are used to store extra data with an element. They can have _any_ name as long as it starts with `data-`, the `expected` part was my own choice.